# How to avoid repeating GUID in deployment definition

Tags: docker, configuration, kubernetes, containers

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-2993d9d2-5cb4-4f4c-a9f3-ec630036f5d0
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      client: 2993d9d2-5cb4-4f4c-a9f3-ec630036f5d0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        client: 2993d9d2-5cb4-4f4c-a9f3-ec630036f5d0
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: xxx
        image: xxx
        env:
        - name: GUID
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.template.metadata.labels.client
```

I tried passing existing value from the definition to the env variable using different expressions and all of them didnt work:

```
error converting fieldPath: field label not supported: spec.template.metadata.labels.client
```

upd: found what [you can pass in](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/core/v1/conversion.go), doesnt help...

I have to essentially repeat myself 4 times, is there a way to have less repeating in the pod definition to ease management? According to [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) you can pass in something, it doesnt say what though.

ps. Do i really need same guid in the spec.template and spec.selector? It doesnt work without that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t necessarily need to use guids here, those are just lables and names...
Secondly, they refer to different things (althought some of them have to be the same in some cases):

- metadata name is name of Deployment in question. You will use it to reference and manipulator this specific Deployment during its lifecycle.
- labels and matchlabels need to be the same if you want them matched together, which in this case you want. Kubernetes is strong and quite flexible when it comes to labeling and different assets can have multiple labels on them (say pod can have labels: app:Postfix, tier: backend, layer: mysql, env:dev). It stands to reason that label(s) that you want matched and label(s) to be matched have to be the same in order to be matched.

As for automation of labeling in Deployment to avoid repetition, maybe helm Charts or some other ‘automating kubernetes’ approach, depending on your actual need, would be better?

Additional note: for passing label to env variable following can be used starting from kubernetes 1.9:

```
...
template:
  metadata:
    labels:
      label_name: label-value
...
env:
  - name: ENV_NAME
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.labels['label_name']
```

Below is full mock code to demonstrate this (client 1.9.3, server 1.9.0):

```
# cat d.yaml:

apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-guidhere
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      client: guidhere
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        client: guidhere
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: some-name
        image: nginx
        env:
          - name: GUIDENV
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.labels['client']

 # after: kubectl create -f d.yaml and connecting to container
 # echo $GUIDENV responds with "guidhere"
```

And I've just tried this and works correctly (mind k8s versions).

Comment: well, i have to use guids there, because that the only way to identify application that is running on the container and it doesnt really change anything, if i choose anything else to put there I will still have to put it in 4 places.

Comment: Then basically, yes, you will have to repeat it for times fo that naming convention. Deployment name and container name doesn’t necessarily have to share GUID though, and depending on your service/namespace convention you might reduce duplication to only two - label and match label.

Comment: container name doesnt have guid in it.

Comment: also, this doesnt answer the main question, how to pull guid from matchLabel\label

Comment: Well, since you need to have them that way you might look into some templating k8s solution such as Helm (if you have more involved setup) or even go as simple as sed and avoid duplication in unelegant yet efficient way

Comment: Just as a sidenote for passing fieldRef: from kubernetes 1.9 you can pass like this: filedPath: metadata.labels['label'], in your case metadata.labels['client']. This reduces at least one place od repetition.

Comment: `error converting fieldPath: field label not supported: metadata.labels['client']`

Comment: What is your kubernetes version? Just tried your example with that and it works (for image I've used nginx, just to get it running). And env is properly propagated. Has to be 1.9+

Comment: Also if your k8s version is too low,  have you tried metadata.name (that would put yout deployment name to env var and since it is app-GUID you could shorten it to GUID and get it from there as workaround)?

Comment: name works, but it sets pod name, not deployment name. k8s 1.8.7, cant upgrade, its a PaaS service. tried that long time ago (i mean `metadata.name`)

Comment: Yes, 1.8.7 won't have it... Maybe separate namespace per GUID and metadata.namespace is a bit far fetched as workaround, although since labels are local to namespace this would make guid in label/match unnecessary.

Comment: sorry, forgot about this one. works after updating k8s